# C# Custom attributes passed down to called methods

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a way to get custom attributes which are added along the flow? I'm adding custom attributes to different methods in different classes that are called depending on the flow. I've tried MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod() but this (as it says) only the current invoked method. Using new StackFrame(n) also doesn't work since "n" can frequently change. Googled my problem but didn't find any hints.

```
public class CustomAttribute1 : Attribute 
{
    public bool Property { get; }

    public CustomAttribute1(bool property) => Property = property;
}

public class CustomAttribute2 : Attribute
{
    public string Property { get; }

    public CustomAttribute2(string property) => Property = property;
}


public class GeneralService 
{
    protected void Resolve() 
    {
        // Here I want to access custom attributes combined 
    }
}

public class SpecifiedService : GeneralService
{
    [CustomAttribute1(true)]
    public void SendRequest() 
    {
        Resolve();
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    [CustomAttribute2("init")]
    public void Init()
    {
        var service = new SpecifiedService();
        service.SendRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not adding parameter to `Resolve`, which inherited classes use as they like? What if `Resolve()` method is called from method without attribute?

Comment: @Sinatr since this method can be called by several services and its logic is dependent on attributes properties, adding them there will serve no purpose. Example is just a simplification.

Comment: you need `StackTrace` not `StackFrame` and iterate frames ... but seriously it's looks some horror coding  ... anyway: `new StackTrace().GetFrames().SelectMany(f =>f.GetMethod().GetCustomAttributes())` and select only the one you need

Comment: *"its logic is dependent on attributes properties"* - make logic depending on parameters. What you are trying to do? Is it some form of *functional programming*?

Comment: [an example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/STSrUJ)  (i've added MyCustomAttribute as our common Attribute base to easy search)... again ... **it's really terrble idea:** it's heavy and there is no way for easy testing

Comment: [better solution](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c7zodk) instead Attributes you are using generic `Dictionary<string, object>` parameter for each method call and you are adding all necesery parameters there